# CSS text reveal on hover with z-index is causing divs to move

Tags: html, css, z-index

When I hover over my first div to reveal the full text, the second div's position changes to go behind that first div. I need the second div to remain where it is, with the text from the first div overlapping it.

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/adivity/pen/OJEzoPm

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1) This is the full title that I want to be revealed. That is super duper long and totally will overlap the next div.
    </div>
    <div>2) This is the full title that I want to be revealed. That is super duper long and totally will overlap the next div.
    </div>
    <div>3) This is the full title that I want to be revealed. That is super duper long and totally will overlap the next div.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.container {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container div {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: grey;
  
}
.container div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
 
}
.container div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 100px;
 }
```

Comment: Why is there a random `position: absolute;`?

Answer (score 1):

Removing `position: absolute` from `.container div:hover` fixed the issue for me. Is that what you were looking for?

```
.container div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute; <---remove this
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Whoops,  in the codepen, I shortened the title to make it clearer, but that the titles are too short. I've updated the codepen. I can get the text to overlap, but I need there to be a background to the text as well.

Comment: Could you try this? 
`.container div:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: red;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.container div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
    <div>2) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
    <div>3) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually overlapping but you'll have to remove the background color of the divs to see the overlap.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container div {
  height: 100px;
/*   background-color: grey; */
}
.container div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
    <div>2) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
    <div>3) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want the divs to stay at their own positions, just remove the "position: absolute" rule fron the css.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container div {
  height: 100px;
/*   background-color: grey; */
}
.container div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.container div:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  z-index: 2;
/*   position: absolute; */
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>1) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
    <div>2) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
    <div>3) This is the full title that I want to be revealed
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The position:absolute was needed for extra long titles. I've updated the codepen, I need a background to the text and I want to extend the div to cover it